# Sorting multidimensional array by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've an array as such

```
Array
(
    [General] => Array
        (
            [Most controversial member] => Array
                (
                    [type] => options
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [tooth] => 1
                            [asprin] => 0
                            [sparks] => 1
                        )

                    [totalVoteCount] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

Using the `rsort` function, I tried to sort the values by the count of the `options` array with the following:

```
foreach($data as $title => $array)
{
    foreach($array as $subheading => $key)
    {
        if($key['type'] == 'options')
        {                
            rsort($key['options']);                
        }
    }
}
```

But the results are still not printing in descending order.

### Expectation

[image]

### Reality

[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but can't figure out even after 2 hours now :(

## UPDATE

I managed to get the sorting working but the keys get messed up

```
foreach($data as $key1 => $array)
{
    foreach($array as $key2 => $key)
    {
        if($key['type'] == 'options')
        {   
            rsort($data[$key1][$key2]['options'], SORT_NUMERIC);                        
        }
    }
}
```

The resultant is as such:
[image]

Is there a way to preserve the keys? i.e `asprin`, `tooth`, `sparks`?

Comment: So you wish to have keys with value 1 to come before keys with value 0?

Comment: Yes, but it won't just be confined to 0 and 1. It's actually the vote count. So it could be anything. Like `0,0,2` or `1,1,1` or `3,0,0`

Comment: Ok, fair enough. If the vote counts are same for 2 keys, then how do you wish to sort the 2 keys?

Comment: If it's the same, then the order or the keys does not matter - just that the vote count should be descending.

Comment: Looking at the update, using `arsort` should do the trick.

Comment: Yep, that's what I went ahead with. Only if I waited a little longer before posting this #facePalm

Comment: That's ok, you still have the option to delete.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solved it.

```
foreach($data as $key1 => $array)
{
    foreach($array as $key2 => $meta)
    {
        if($meta['type'] == 'options')
        {
            arsort($meta['options'], SORT_NUMERIC);                                        
            $data[$key1][$key2]['options'] = $meta['options'];
        }
    }
}
```